# MVC4 user registration using existing database through repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

First I need to say that I'm total new to MVC and I'm sorry about that possibly silly question.
I tried to find some some articles that will help me to solve my issue but in vain.
I've created database using EF6 Code First. After that I've created my repository pattern that helps me to operate with it(add, delete, edit ...).
Then I've created my MVC4 project(which is top level of my solution) with existing user registration and tried to deal it with my repository pattern but I've failed while using **webSecurity** and **membership** classes. These static classes provide great possibility for different actions with users, however I can't use them because each of them create own database or use existing DbConnection(in this case there's no sense to use my repository). So is there a way to use something like **webSecurity** or **membership** ? May be I can create my own?
I'll be grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, Yes you can have your own membership provider with EF and MVC...

This sample code will guide you on how to do that:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30514/Custom-membership-provider-for-the-ADO-NET-Entity